# SQL TEXT type in Dataset Designer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, xsd

I'm using Visual Studio's designer to create a typed data set, and I've changed one of the fields in the stored procedure to be a TEXT type. I now can't refresh as the TEXT type is not comparable.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a Text type. You have much more flexibility using nvarchar(max) or varchar(max). This should map to a string type in your typed dataset.